# How to redirect to Ionic app after Facebook login flow?

Tags: cordova, oauth, ionic-framework, ngcordova, openfb

After problems using ngCordova OAuth I decided to implement OAuth through use of OpenFB, I followed the tutorial here:

https://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/ionic-facebook-integration.html

This is completely fine for when developing locally within browser, however when using IonicView to test the application on my iPhone, the user can login successfully but the callback doesn't redirect to the app instead it just stops on a blank html file reading this

'Success
SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone. See the Facebook Help Centre for more information.'

It is probably a quick fix but I can't seem to find any useful info online. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I have similar issue, Have you found a solution for this ?